# How are properties defined in a class diagram when using UML?

Tags: uml

I am trying to wrap my head around how class diagrams are constructed when development has not commenced. My understanding is that you put together UML diagrams prior to any development. I came across an article at http://digitsby.me/2010/01/14/idiots-guid-to-uml-class-diagrams.html.

If I look under the heading 'class' I see a description about the properties of a class e.g. Forename, Surname, etc

1. How are these defined if development has not yet commenced?
2. How is a class name given seeing that development has not commenced?
3. I assume when it refers to public and private it means that in the case of the former, the property is accessible by any other object and whilst private, it is limited to the User class. Is that correct?
4. Why is there a divider between e.g. salt,  and e.g. login, logout?
5. Do class diagrams only come after use case and activity diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1&2: Think about your functional context. You have to make a software to manage, say, a library? You'll probably manipulate books, so you will have a "book" in UML. And you'll probably need to know the title and the author of the book. So naturally, using UML, you'll create a UML class named Book with attributes title and author. And you don't need to know that it will really correspond to a real class in a real dev language.

3: It is correct.

4: Above the divider are the attributes, below are the operations (i.e. methods)

5: There is no unique answer to this question. It depends on your project method. UML does not tell you when to use which diagram, t only gives you tools. Personnally, I like to begin with use cases, that I consider fundamental, and then I like to make a first very general class diagram, with only the main classes and the very important attributes (no operations, no visibility), in order to clarify a global vision of the data involved. Then I further detail the processes with activity diagrams, detailed class diagrams and sequence diagrams. But this how I like to work, not a general requirement.

Comment: Thanks Steph. That made much more sense although I am still a little fuzzy on point 5. Had a look at your profile and it mentions that you are a part time UML trainer. Would you mind if I emailed you my diagrams to review and comment so that I can better improve? Unfortunately no one I know uses UML and its difficult to know whether I am going offtrack. My email address is my username followed by gmail [.] com

Comment: When describing the system requirements 'Domain Objects' will emerge, these will typically be nouns and nearly always exist as a Class (or multiple classes).  The verbs that qualify the Class name will often be it's operations or methods.

Comment: @Martin Spamer - That's where I get confused. Is there a real world example of domain objects?

Comment: 'Domain' refers to the subject matter you are working in, so in an Business accounting system, examples of domain objects would be Invoice, CreditNote, Balance, Transaction etc.

Comment: Hi@Steph!`UML does not tell you when to use which diagram`
How can I know that I should use this diagram in this case?